# Ubuntu server destroyed my raid5 array

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a machine running Ubuntu server at home with a 4 drive mdadm ext4 raid5 array.  It was running 20.04.4 until about 3-4 weeks ago when I upgraded it to 22.04.  It was running well until 5 days ago when the system froze.  It was the first and only time it did so.  I restarted it by powercycling and the system then refused to boot giving me this error:

> mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)

After a while a message about maintencance mode came up.  Proceeding normally would cause the maintenance mode message to reappear.  So I went into maintenance mode and commented out the line in fstab for the array and the system booted fine.

Fast forward to today when I found some time to look into this properly.  After some searching I found that others had similar issues and the top recommendation was to revert back to 20.04 until it's resolved.  So I installed 20.04 desktop on a spare ssd and opened the Disks utility. All 4 drives have a single partition on them saying:

> Contents Unknown (zfs_member 5000)

I never formatted the array to ZFS, I never even installed zfs on linux on that machine.  I don't know if it's included by default on Ubuntu now.

I then fired up the terminal and ran

> sudo mdadm -As

and received a message that no arrays were found.

I then tried to restore the array manually by copying the appropriate lines from /etc/fstab and /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf on my original system drive.  The system hangs for a bit and then boots into the desktop environment.  The message when it hangs is

> A start job is running for /dev/md0

which is the raid array I'm attempting to mount.

Did Ubuntu really format the array to ZFS without me telling it to?  Is my data gone without any hope of recovery?

**Edit 1:** As @matigo suggested, I have checked `/var/log/syslog`. It appears the ZFS kernel module was present on the system the day it froze. The earliest entry in the log is May 09 and from that day until the system froze the only entries with ZFS are the same as this one `May  9 00:24:01 crypt CRON[998052]: (root) CMD (if [ $(date +%w) -eq 0 ] && [ -x /usr/lib/zfs-linux/scrub ]; then /usr/lib/zfs-linux/scrub; fi)`. On that day this entry with ZFS appeared along with some relevant entries about the array.

> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    3.264285] md/raid:md0: device sdc operational as raid disk 2
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    3.264317] md/raid:md0: device sdb operational as raid disk 3
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    3.264340] md/raid:md0: device sdd operational as raid disk 0
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    3.264362] md/raid:md0: device sde operational as raid disk 1
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    3.265073] md/raid:md0: raid level 5 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    3.287846] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 17580804096
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.296378]
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.297538]  bio_put+0x83/0x100
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.298698]  end_bio_bh_io_sync+0x37/0x50
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.299857]  bio_endio+0xfd/0x160
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.301006] md_end_io_acct+0x3f/0x50
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.302146]  bio_endio+0xfd/0x160
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.303269]  handle_failed_stripe+0x4fc/0x550 [raid456]
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.304401]  handle_stripe+0xd7b/0xfd0 [raid456]
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.305529]  handle_active_stripes.constprop.0+0xce/0x290 [raid456]
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.306671]  ? md_wakeup_thread+0x2e/0x60
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.307813]  ? do_release_stripe+0x11c/0x390 [raid456]
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.308813] ZFS: Loaded module v2.1.2-1ubuntu3, ZFS pool version 5000, ZFS filesystem version 5
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.308965]  raid5d+0x35f/0x560 [raid456]
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.311308]  md_thread+0xad/0x160
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.312472]  ? wait_woken+0x70/0x70
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.313638]  ? md_write_inc+0x50/0x50
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.314768]  kthread+0x12a/0x150
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.315858]  ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.316945]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.318036]
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.491050] JBD2: recovery failed
>
> Jul 25 15:25:44 crypt kernel: [    6.492560] EXT4-fs (md0): error loading journal

Comment: It is unlikely that the OS did anything to the RAID disks without consent. You may want to check your `/var/log/syslog` file for any error messages pertaining to the disks and/or mdadm. This will give you something more specific and (hopefully) actionable to work with 

Comment: I will check `/var/log/syslog` now.  I am aware that it's unlikely the system did something to the disks without consent, however it seems that that is in fact what happened.  The system runs unattended for weeks at a time. I only ssh into it to update it every month or so. I update my docker containers using portainer more frequently than that though, every couple of weeks or so.  The last time I did something to it was when I upgraded it to 22.04.